# JavaScript - Maintaining Global Reference to Element Found Using getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, global, getelementsbytagname

Let's say I wanted to find the last div on the page and do so using `getElementsByTagName` as below:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var div = divs[divs-1];
```

This all works fine, unless I want to access said div inside a function:

```
function a() {
 alert(div);
}
```

This results in an alert saying 'undefined'. However, if I know the ID of the div and find it using `getElementById` instead, the above function works as I would expect.

[jsFiddle to illustrate what I mean.](http://jsfiddle.net/8T4CM/)

Can anyone tell me how I can maintain a global reference to an element when using `getElementsByTagName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed `.length` within `[]`. Try:

```
var div = divs[divs.length-1];
                     //^-----------------total amount of divs
```

instead of:

```
var div = divs[divs-1];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that was a mistake in my simplification of the code for the example. Actual mistake turned out to be just as stupid - I was using a variable with the same name elsewhere. Thanks for your help though.